# Switching ViewControllers with UISegmentedControl in iOS5

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying something very simple but somehow I can't get it to work. All I try to do is switching between 2 View Controllers using an UISegmentedControl as you can see it for example in the App Store application in the Highlights tab.

I am using iOS5 and Storyboards.

Here's my Storyboad line up:

[image]

So I have a root View Controller and two UITableViews - This 2 TableViews I want to switch.

Here's how the implementation file looks like

```
#import "SegmentedLocationViewController.h"
#import "PastEventsLocationViewController.h"
#import "FutureEventsLocationViewController.h"

@interface SegmentedLocationViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *viewControllers;
@end


@implementation SegmentedLocationViewController

@synthesize segmentedControl = _segmentedControl;
@synthesize viewControllers = _viewControllers;

- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl*)segmentedControl
{
    NSLog(@"index: %d", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
}

- (void)setupViewControllers
{
    PastEventsLocationViewController *pastEventsLocationViewController = [[PastEventsLocationViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    FutureEventsLocationViewController *futureEventsLocationViewController = [[FutureEventsLocationViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pastEventsLocationViewController, futureEventsLocationViewController, nil];
}

- (void)setupUI
{
    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupViewControllers];
    [self setupUI];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I can trigger the switch event and can log the currently selected index. But I don't have any idea where to go from here.

Maybe someone can turn my attention towards a certain direction...?

Comment: have you thought about just reloading the tableView with different values?

Comment: You're right. I will check that now. I might think too complicated...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This code works pretty well for your purpose, I use it for one of my new apps.
It uses the new UIViewController containment APIs that allow UIViewControllers inside your own UIViewControllers without the hassles of manually forwarding stuff like `viewDidAppear:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // add viewController so you can switch them later. 
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerForSegmentIndex:self.typeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    self.currentViewController = vc;
}
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerForSegmentIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:vc duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
        [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
        [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        self.currentViewController = vc;
    }];
    self.navigationItem.title = vc.title;
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    UIViewController *vc;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FooViewController"];
            break;
        case 1:
            vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BarViewController"];
            break;
    }
    return vc;
}
```

I got this stuff from chapter 22 of Ray Wenderlichs book [iOS5 by tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-5-by-tutorials). 
Unfortunately I don't have a public link to a tutorial. But there is a WWDC 2011 video titled "Implementing UIViewController Containment"

**EDIT**

`self.typeSegmentedControl` is outlet for your `UISegmentedControl`

`self.contentView` is outlet for your container view

`self.currentViewController` is just a property that we're using to store our currently used `UIViewController`

Comment: I did not make it with the storyboards but when I use your code with nib-files it works... So thanks you get my vote ;)

Comment: This rocks man. I just discovered [self storyboard] after 2 months. Thanks!!

Comment: This might seem like a stupid question, but when starting from scratch I get issues such as this Property 'typeSegmentedControl' not found on object of type 'ViewController *' I'm probably doing something stupid aren't I

Comment: you have to add the `@property` for `typeSegmentedControl` (UISegmentedControl)

Comment: I moved `vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;` outside the animation block to avoid subviews exceeding the contentView's bounds during transition, which otherwise caused a flicker.

Comment: I had to implement self.contentView.frame = self.view.frame; inside viewDidLoad cause my Container has size 0 after launching the application.

Answer (score 10):

It's Matthias Bauch solution, but thought of sharing it in Swift anyway!
**Edit:**
Adding a link to a Swift 2.0 ready made demo app.
https://github.com/ahmed-abdurrahman/taby-segmented-control

```
var currentViewController: UIViewController?
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func switchHappeningTabs(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if let vc = viewControllerForSelectedSegmentIndex(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.transitionFromViewController(self.currentViewController!, toViewController: vc, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.currentViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
            vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds
            self.contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
            }, completion: { finished in
                vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
                self.currentViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()
                self.currentViewController = vc
            }
        )        
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let vc = self.viewControllerForSelectedSegmentIndex(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
        self.currentViewController = vc
    }
}

func viewControllerForSelectedSegmentIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
    var vc: UIViewController?
    switch index {
    case 0:
            vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FooViewController") as? UIViewController
    case 1:
            vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BarViewController") as? UIViewController
    default:
        return nil
    }

    return vc
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot ! This made my day :)

Comment: Sure, it's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 4):

For someone want to implement the same in swift

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UIViewController {

    var currentViewController:UIViewController?

    @IBOutlet weak var homeController: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let initialController:UIViewController = self.viewControllerForSegmentedIndex(0)

        self.addChildViewController(initialController)

        initialController.view.frame = self.homeController.bounds
        self.homeController.addSubview(initialController.view)
        self.currentViewController = initialController

    }

    @IBAction func segmentChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        let viewCOntroller:UIViewController = viewControllerForSegmentedIndex(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

        self.addChildViewController(viewCOntroller)

        self.transitionFromViewController(self.currentViewController!, toViewController: viewCOntroller, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {
            self.currentViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            viewCOntroller.view.frame = self.homeController.bounds
            self.homeController.addSubview(viewCOntroller.view)

            }, completion:{ finished in

                viewCOntroller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
                self.currentViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
                self.currentViewController = viewCOntroller

        })

    }
    func viewControllerForSegmentedIndex(index:Int) -> UIViewController {
        var viewController:UIViewController?
        switch index {
        case 0:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdForFirstController")
            break
        case 1:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdForSecondController")
            break
        case 2:
            viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdForThirdController")
            break
        default:
            break
        }
        return viewController!
    }
}
```

Storyboard view

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A is root view controller, and B, C is sub view controller.
When you click segment, add sub view controller.

**result**

[image: result]

**design**

[image: design]

**code**

```
import UIKit

class SegmentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    var leftViewController: LeftViewController!
    var rightViewController: RightViewController!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if let sb = storyboard {
            leftViewController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftViewController") as! LeftViewController

            switchViewController(from: nil, to: leftViewController)
        } else {
            print("storyboard is nil")
        }
    }

    func switchViewController(from fromVC: UIViewController?, to toVC: UIViewController?) {
        if let from = fromVC {
            from.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
            from.view.removeFromSuperview()
            from.removeFromParentViewController()
        } else {
            print("fromVC is nil")
        }

        if let to = toVC {
            self.addChildViewController(to)
            to.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.width, containerView.frame.height)
            self.containerView.insertSubview(to.view, atIndex: 0)
            to.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        } else {
            print("toVC is nil")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

        removeViewController()
    }

    func removeViewController() {
        if let leftVC = leftViewController {
            if let _ = leftVC.parentViewController {
                print("leftVC is using")
            } else {
                print("set leftVC = nil")
                leftViewController = nil
            }
        }

        if let rightVC = rightViewController {
            if let _ = rightVC.parentViewController {
                print("rightVC is using")
            } else {
                print("set rightVC = nil")
                rightViewController = nil
            }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func onSegmentValueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        UIView.beginAnimations("xxx", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.4)
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(.EaseInOut)

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            UIView.setAnimationTransition(.FlipFromRight, forView: self.containerView, cache: true)

            if let leftVC = leftViewController {
                switchViewController(from: rightViewController, to: leftVC)
            } else {
                if let sb = storyboard {
                    leftViewController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftViewController") as! LeftViewController
                    switchViewController(from: rightViewController, to: leftViewController)
                } else {
                    print("storyboard is nil")
                }
            }
        default:
            UIView.setAnimationTransition(.FlipFromLeft, forView: self.containerView, cache: true)

            if let rightVC = rightViewController {
                switchViewController(from: leftViewController, to: rightVC)
            } else {
                if let sb = storyboard {
                    rightViewController = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rightViewController") as! RightViewController
                    switchViewController(from: leftViewController, to: rightViewController)
                } else {
                    print("storyboard is nil")
                }
            }
        }

        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could embed your initial view controller in a navigation controller. Do that by selecting the view controller in the storyboard, then Editor->Embed in->Navigation Controller.

In your indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl: method you simply push the corresponding view controller to the navigation stack:

```
- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl*)segmentedControl
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[segmentedControl.selectedIndex]] animated:YES];

}
```

But your approach makes not too much sense at all when you are using storyboards.
I don't know whether you can wire up a single segmented control button to a view controller using segues. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a navigation controller to achieve a similar functionality.

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

  var currentSegmentIndex = 0

  @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = currentSegmentIndex
  }

  @IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let idx = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    switch idx {
    case 0:
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
        withIdentifier: "Foo") as! FooViewController
      vc.currentSegmentIndex = 0
      navigationController?.viewControllers = [vc]
      break
    case 1:
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(
        withIdentifier: "Bar") as! BarViewController
      vc.currentSegmentIndex = 1
      navigationController?.viewControllers = [vc]
      break
    default:
      break
    }
  }
}
```