# Tabbed form on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, forms, uitableview

I have just started programming on iOS a couple of weeks ago, so sorry if these questions are really basic.

Short story: I am designing a CRM app that needs capturing a lot of customer data.  I am trying to emulate a desktop app that uses tabbed forms.  What would be the best way (technically and visually) to implement this on an iPad?

I need the following:

- each tab (5-6 of them) to contain a number of fields (with labels) of various types, for which I would love to use specialized controls (eg uidatepicker, uipickerview/uisegmentedcontrol, textarea+stepper, switch etc.), not just raw text fields
- ideally (actually this is a pretty key requirement) the UI would have to be generated programatically, so that a change of model wouldn't require manually adjusting the forms in IB
- be able to switch between tabs without losing the data already entered in the current tab.

My progress so far, re. overall switching mechanism:

- I initially thought to have the tabs switcher implemented as a segmented control, switching between different views as described in Matthias' comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110567/switching-viewcontrollers-with-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios5).  Instantiating VCs on demand however means losing the data already entered (unless I'd implement some sort of caching, but I'm hoping for something simpler).
- I'm now considering the much easier approach of switching views by showing/hiding them programatically, but I'm afraid this might use too much memory (I'm looking at possibly over 100 fields in total).

As for representing the form fields within each tab:

- I could lay them out manually in IB (or as static cells in a tableview) but I'd really prefer not to do that, as it would basically mean the UI is hardcoded and hard to change
- I'd prefer to create the interface programatically, but I don't know how easy it is to handle the different field types, attach popups (e.g. for datepickers for date fields), handle field events etc.

If someone has any pointers I could use, I'd really appreciate it.

TIA,
Lucian

Comment: Are you using UITabBarController for your tab based application? In which manner those tabs are?

Comment: Yes, I'm already using UITabBarController, but for the main sections of the app, so it's not an option to implement the form tabs as tab bar items.  That's why I was looking at uisegmentedcontroller or something similar.  The form tabs would have to be displayed in a subview and not take the full screen.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Custom Buttons, which looks like UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with one view controller, owning one view that then has sub-views that you hide/show as needed.

Broadly:

- one top level UIView, which contains the tab buttons (use ordinary UIButtons for this), and owns several UIViews
- Each UIView has the fields needed for each "tab"

Then to switch tabs, just hide one view and show another and all will be well.

I wouldn't worry about memory consumption - an iPad has easily enough memory for 100s of UI controls, since I don't expect you'd be doing lots of custom graphics. If you do run low on memory, you can always just create the controls as needed for each tab - it will take a bit longer to switch tabs, but would work.

As for programmatically laying things out: this is entirely possible. You have 2 basic options when creating an iPad UI - use XIB files (designed using the graphical designer in XCode), or doing it in code, typically in `-viewWillAppear` or `-viewDidLoad`. All the relevant things can be done - look at the docs for each UI control to figure out how to configure it.