# UIKit controller/view to switch between views?

Tags: ios, uikit

Sorry for novice question if it is.

I have my controller/view with `UISegmentedControl`. I need to switch between controllers/views to let the views take the rest of the screen. The idea is pretty similar to `UITabBarController` but switching controls are not tab buttons but segment controls. How can i achieve it according to iOS design and practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a container viewController and include tis logics:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *containerView;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentSelectedIndex;



_segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
[_segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


- (void)changeViewController:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl
{
    UIViewController *oldViewController = self.viewControllers[self.currentSelectedIndex];
    UIViewController *newViewController = self.viewControllers[segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];

    [self willTransitionToViewController:newViewController];
    [self transitionFromViewController:oldViewController
                      toViewController:newViewController
                              duration:0
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                            animations:nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if (finished)
                                    [self didTransitionToViewController:newViewController];
                            }];
}


- (void)showFirstViewController
{
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [self.viewControllers firstObject];

    // set required the frame
    firstViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    firstViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.containerView addSubview:firstViewController.view];

    [self willTransitionToViewController:firstViewController];
    [self didTransitionToViewController:firstViewController];
}



- (void)willTransitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.currentSelectedIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment)
    {

        UIViewController *oldViewController = self.viewControllers[self.currentSelectedIndex];
        [oldViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    }

    viewController.containerView.frame = self.ContainerView.bounds;
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}

- (void)didTransitionToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    self.currentSelectedIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

}
```

Comment: will this set new selected controller as current and show its view to the whole screen ?

Comment: Yes . you need to add segment control to view and also add one more container view below the segment control and add viewControllers view to container view.

Comment: no, i need to make the view take only part of the screen  below segmented control and not just set new controller/view.

Comment: Read last Comment , i explained how to make make the view take only part of the screen below segmented control.I edited Code also.

Comment: what is `UIView *containerView;` and how is it initialized?

Comment: _containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frameBelowSegmentControl]; and [self.view addSubView:_containerView];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56320/discussion-between-yatheesha-and-4ntoine).

Answer (score 0):

You can take base view on that add a UISegmentedControl and handle the click event in BASE view controller.
On segment control click event just add and remove the respective view controller on the base view.

Comment: can you provide an example? i need to have separate controller/view for each "section"

Comment: Please go through the following link it describe the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110567/switching-viewcontrollers-with-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios5

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, Have one Main ViewController with segment, Say`MainViewC` and take two different View Controllers say `ViewAVC` and `ViewBVC`inside this `MainViewC`

Add All your subviews that you want to show in ViewA and ViewB.

Add these View Controllers to `MainViewC` with setting a proper frame for each ViewController.

Now while you add the segmentControl You can add a target function in the following way

```
itemArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Zero", @"One", nil];
seg = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
[seg setFrame:segRect];
seg.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
seg.momentary = NO;
[seg addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mainView addSubview:seg];
```

In this function `someAction:` check what is the currently selected value of the segment and Hide one view and unhide other.

This way you will have seperate View Controller, but when you wish to interact between these View Controllers and `MainViewC` you will require to add a few delegates

Comment: then i need to create view for each controller manually and have all the code for sections in my controller which is not good IMHO as it becomes too big and have logic of section controllers

Comment: You can always use .xib for each View, and also have separate classes for you views.

Comment: sure but all the logic is in controllers and i don't want to have the logics of all the sections in one controller

Comment: Updated the answer. check it out