# Switch screen to black and white programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm looking for any way to switch mac screen to black and white mode programmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047114/how-do-i-use-a-uisegmentedcontrol-to-switch-views

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110567/switching-viewcontrollers-with-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios5

Comment: I need switch mac screen (with other apps), not screen of my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function CGDisplayForceToGray and [blacktree-nocturne sources](https://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/) has helped me.

Comment: This no longer works in macOS 13.

Comment: It was non-public function in the Core Graphics framework. Now we have real grayscale mode, check https://github.com/rkbhochalya/grayscale-mode or apple script way https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252763839