# Switching viewControllers with a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to implement the code described in this [tutorial](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited) to switch `UIViewController`s using an `UISegmentedControl`. The tutorial uses `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to set everything up and show the first view:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSArray * viewControllers = [self segmentViewControllers];

    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.segmentsController = [[SegmentsController alloc] initWithNavigationController:navigationController viewControllers:viewControllers];

    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)]];

    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self.segmentsController
                          action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self firstUserExperience];

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

However, in my app, I'd like to call this from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` inside a `UITableViewController`, but I'm not sure how to do that. So the user selects a row, and a new view appears where I can switch between views using a `UISegmentedControl` at the top.

I guess the line that needs to change is `[window addSubview:navigationController.view];`, all the rest can be the same.

What would be the equivalent if I call that code from my `UITableViewController` instead of from the `AppDelegate` as in the tutorial ?

(This is not a duplicate of [Switching ViewControllers with UISegmentedControl in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110567/switching-viewcontrollers-with-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios5), since I'd like to use the example from the tutorial and that question deals with how to set it up using storyboards.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't think this is a nice solution (I would prefer creating a separate view controller, with the segmented control, and implement the switching logic there), the answer is **yes**: you can call this piece of code from your table view controller, adding the navigation controller's view as its subview, like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    NSArray * viewControllers = [self segmentViewControllers];
    
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.segmentsController = [[SegmentsController alloc] initWithNavigationController:navigationController viewControllers:viewControllers];
    
    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)]];
    self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    
    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self.segmentsController
                              action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self firstUserExperience];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    
}
```

I have downloaded the example you referred to (quite outdated by the way), and included it in a sample project. so you can check it out. All you need to do is add a new item, then select a row to invoke the relevant code piece.

[Check the code here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7fd9ed87ed53f389!6314&authkey=!AO0L3j67haNdFa0&ithint=folder%2c)

#### UPDATE:

I have added a second example which uses a separate view controller, check it out if you want: [Link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7fd9ed87ed53f389!6359&authkey=!AJ2e_TkAASFlkgk&ithint=folder%2c)

Comment: I like the second approach. The only thing is that I see a black glow under the navigationbar, but that could be something in my code that is causing that, since i don't see it in your example.

Comment: I just threw the example code into the master-data app template in Xcode, so I didn't really think about it. You can try to use the built-in view debugger to examine your layout at runtime.

Comment: Adding `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` seems to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the container view controller. The tutorial you're referring to was a hack used prior to container view controllers. The author should really pull that thing down.